# Como reverter o FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS

Tags: php

Galera eu peguei uma variável e converti ela usando o `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`.

Exemplo:

```
filter_var ("hug' o", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

O resultado:

```
hugD&#39; o
```

Como faço para reverter isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a função [`html_entity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
$foo = filter_var ("hug' o", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

echo html_entity_decode($foo, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8"); // hug' o
```

Comment: muito bom, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a página de [SANITIZE do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php), a encodação foi em ASCII. Mas como esse caso está encodando um apóstrofo, Seria melhor o teu sanitize ser assim:

```
$resposta = filter_var("hug' o",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES)
```

Onde:

> FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING => Sanitiza a String
>
> FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES => Trata o caractere especial, como é o apóstrofo, assim como aspas, tratará.

Comment: vlw, vc me ajudar muito ;)